# In cake PHP 3.0 how to rectify the index page error after installing

Tags: php, cakephp, installation, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cake php. After installing the cake php 3.0 some errors are came in index page like

> Error: Class 'Cake\Mailer\Email' not found File
>   /var/www/html/cake3/config/bootstrap.php Line: 138
>
> Fatal Error Cake\Error\FatalErrorException

can any one help how to fix this errors.

Comment: looks like youre missing bootstrap.php file, did you check if it is there and why not? ever tried to google the error? :P

Comment: no vendors installed ?

Comment: bootstrap.php is there and i googled the error i not get any clear idea.....@mikus

Comment: vendors files are there.@notuser

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (`vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`)!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when installing from the ZIP file.
Use Composer to install or upgrade CakePHP as described here:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp